# I installed Visual Studio 2022 and 2019- computer is saying two versions of one

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, windows-11

I recently got a Win 11 machine and installed Visual Studio 2022, then I installed Visual Studio 2019 to support an old app. In the search feature on the Win task bar, when I enter visual studio it shows them listed like this:

`Visual Studio 2022`

`Visual Studio 2019 (2)`

It has this for "Blend" too.

Is this just from picking the same feature set(s) during the install? For example, SQL Data Tools. And/Or could it mean something isn't right with my env?

VS 2019 is in
`Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

VS 2022 is in `Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\denvenv.exe`

I'm having an issue with an old site in 2019, but I don't believe it's related. I am just curious why that (2) is there and what if any problems it could cause.

Thanks

Comment: The installer probably found (remnants of) another installation and made sure you could distinguish the new installation.

Comment: It is not unusual to see such shortcut names, and you can report to Microsoft (similar to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/when-updating-vs2019-from-rc-to-ga-2-shortcuts-for/510329)

Comment: There is usually no need to install older version of Visual Studio because most of the old tooling can be used from the current version.

Comment: @user7860670 - VS2019 would still be required for SSIS/SSRS projects as they are not available for VS2022 yet. As soon as they are then goodbye 2019.

Comment: user7860670 We have to install VS 2019 for our old solution to work. VS 2022 is for a new system we're developing.